# Spring Boot Togglz - no qualifying bean of type UserProvider error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, togglz

I'm trying to add togglz to my sprint boot application, however on start up I get the following error:

```
2016-12-21 12:41:34.482 ERROR 43583 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter    : Error starting Tomcat context: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException
2016-12-21 12:41:34.530  WARN 43583 --- [  restartedMain] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.togglz.core.user.UserProvider] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1326) ~[spring-beans-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1072) ~[spring-beans-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:967) ~[spring-beans-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:813) ~[spring-beans-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) ~[spring-beans-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    ... 138 common frames omitted
Wrapped by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'featureManager' defined in class path resource [org/togglz/spring/boot/autoconfigure/TogglzAutoConfiguration$FeatureManagerConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 2 of type [org.togglz.core.user.UserProvider]: : No qualifying bean of type [org.togglz.core.user.UserProvider] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.togglz.core.user.UserProvider] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
```

It seems like there's a problem in the configuration, however I seem to have everything in place as recommended at https://www.togglz.org/documentation/spring-boot-starter.html

My setup is as follows:

```
package com.togglz;

import java.io.File;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.togglz.core.Feature;
import org.togglz.core.manager.TogglzConfig;
import org.togglz.core.repository.StateRepository;
import org.togglz.core.repository.file.FileBasedStateRepository;
import org.togglz.core.user.FeatureUser;
import org.togglz.core.user.SimpleFeatureUser;
import org.togglz.core.user.UserProvider;

@Component
public class TogglzConfiguration implements TogglzConfig {

    public Class<? extends Feature> getFeatureClass() {
        return Features.class;
    }

    public StateRepository getStateRepository() {
        return new FileBasedStateRepository(new File("application-local.properties"));
    }

    public UserProvider getUserProvider() {
        return new UserProvider() {
            @Override
            public FeatureUser getCurrentUser() {
                return new SimpleFeatureUser("admin", true);
            }
        };

    }
}
```

and

```
package com.togglz;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.togglz.core.Feature;
import org.togglz.core.annotation.Label;
import org.togglz.core.context.FeatureContext;


    @Component
    public enum Features implements Feature {

        @Label("Feature1")
        FEATURE_ONE,

        @Label("Feature2")
        FEATURE_TWO;

        public boolean isActive() {
            return FeatureContext.getFeatureManager().isActive(this);
        }
    }
```

with my application properties file containing the following:

```
togglz:
  enabled: true
  feature-enums: com.togglz.Features
    FEATURE_ONE: true
    FEATURE_TWO: false
```

Has anyone else experienced this problem or have any idea how to resolve it?  I'd have expected my getUserProvider() to handle things, but possibly not..

Comment: This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44461331/2933389 worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

You are **missing** `@Bean` annotation on your `public UserProvider getUserProvider() {}` function and that is an issue.
Spring is trying to search for userprovider bean which is required by togglz to configure its user provider

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an upgrade of the Spring Boot version did the trick...